# Can't group by year from a date row

Tags: date, drupal, aggregation, drupal-views

I have a field of date-time type. I added this field into a view and formatted the date-time field to show only year. When I switch 'aggregation' on in Views and try to group this field it didn't work as i expect and show all the dates again. I saw the Vies-query and there wasn't any preformatting. It was grouping by dis field only. I want the modify the query to get this fields formatted as I need (years only).

Comment: What display style plugin are you using? ie table? unformatted?...

Comment: table but i think the problem is in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems the aggregation settings work on the query, vs on the results that are output that you've formatted differently.

Here's how you can do the aggregation though:

1. Select the 'Settings' next to the 'Table' format
2. Select your date field (that you only show the year on) under the 'Grouping field Nr. 1'
   [image]
3. Then just exclude that field from the display, since it'll be output at the top in the group
   [image]
4. And here's what the result will be like roughly (for table view... you can try a variety of different ones like lists, etc and style however you like with css).  I'm only outputting the title field for mine
   [image]

Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: 10x I'll try it in a sec and will leave feedback. btw r u Bulgarian? :)

Comment: Didn't work for me :\  After I excluded that field from display it still remained in the "select"  statement and it groups by it in the bottom because aggregation is ON. Despite i hate writing modules seems I'll have to write one to add Date() function in the select statement.

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7?  Turn aggregation off and the above should work.  And yep, I'm Bulgarian. ;-)

Comment: Also, did you do the grouping through the settings next to your table format or list format?  That is the work-around.  It works with just regular views, no additional modules etc necessary.

Comment: Yep it did! (Поздрави от София :Р)

Comment: OK, chudesno. Radvam se, che stana. Small world, nali?